# ASP.NET Core - Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console - Output in green characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor, .net-core-3.0

Sometimes, the output of the Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console switches to green characters. They are staying green until I close the window between the debug sessions. When I close the window and debug it again, only the word "info" on the left is green, as expected.

This happens in an ASP.NET Core MVC project, as well as in a Blazor project. Both .NET Core 3.0.100

There is never a problem with the apps when this happens.

Windows 10 and VS2019 are both latest and greatest as of today.

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console]

Edit 1: The last occurrence was after some changes in the _Layout.cshtml. I was working on div and CSS classes.

Edit 2: After changing the settings as  Ruard van Elburg suggested, it changed a little bit. Now it has shown the first time a mix of colors. So it is obviously a bug.

[image: With changed logging settings]

Comment: When it is green, everything is green from the beginning. It is not changing in the middle of execution. To change the colors, the console window has to be closed.

Comment: I had the same, but more persistent. It stayed green all the time. Changed in appsettings logging from Information to Debug and started the app. Then reverted the changes. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Ok, sorry that was unclear. Is the effect a feature or a bug? I was just wondering.

Comment: Given how I solved it, I would say a bug. Seems the color depends on the first message color and somehow persists it under certain conditions. Changing the logging type seems to reset it.